# compare columns from multiple text files, to csv column file python

Tags: python, text, compare

I have 662 text files in one folder, to open them I used a code I found somwhere around here:

```
os = '..'
path = './'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.*')):
    print('current file is: ' + infile)
```

To exctract the first column I used:

```
with open(infile) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line.split()[0])
```

But here the first problem, it extracts only the first columns of the **last file** nor all the files.

Second problem , I need to compare these columns to first column in csv file.. same as "in.index" option in pandas (but it's csv vs. text)

Comment: the function exctract the first column is inside ""for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.*'))""??

Comment: with open(infile) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line.split()[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it print  last file nor all the files  because you print the columns after the file loop is end
and it print the first column because you write
line.split()[0]

you can make it like this

```
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.*')):
  print('current file is: ' + infile)
  with open(infile) as infile:
      for line in infile:
         for i in range(len(line))
           print(line.split()[i])
```

i just put all the code in one loop and new loop to print all the columns

Comment: I needed only the first column, and yes after putting inside the loop it worked, thanks. The second problem is how to compare the first column of the csv file (index) to first columns which was extracted from the text files (index too)

Comment: please mark the answer as approved answer if it help you to get the all files >>>>>
if you want to get the first column change split()[i] to split()[0] >> what you mean by compare? to check if it equal or not?

Comment: You didn't understand me. I have a file, which isn't in this folder, how do I compare it's first column to the first columns in the "txt" files

Comment: ok this anther question create new one and i will help you and mark my answer as accepted  if it help you in print all the file in this folder

Comment: Thank you,  I want to try by myself a little and then post it